# Match to capture groups globally in bash

Tags: bash

Have this dead-simple perl script:

```
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use warnings;

my $str = q{some [values] in string [enclosed] [in some] number of [square brackets]};
my @matches;
if(my $num =(@matches)= $str =~ / \[ (.*?) \] /gsx ) {
        say "got $num matches:";
        say "[$_]" for @matches;
}
```

it prints:

```
got 4 matches:
[values]
[enclosed]
[in some]
[square brackets]
```

How to implement something like in `bash`?

*Ps: didn't provide any bash code, because i don't know how to even start. The `${BASH_REMATCH[@]}` doesn't works globally in one line... For using the `BASH_REMATCH` need to know in advance the number of cature groups. So, haven't idea... :( The closest what i could is:*

```
str='some [values] in string [enclosed] [in some] number of [square brackets]'
echo "$str"
mapfile -t arr < <(grep -oP '\[\K(.*?)(?=])' <<< "$str")
echo "got ${#arr[@]} matches"
printf "[%s]\n" "${arr[@]}"
```

but it uses grep with perl-regexes...

Is possible to do this in pure bash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bash` regular expression matching doesn't provide this support. You need to simulate it by iterating over an ever-shrinking input string.

```
str='some [values] in string [enclosed] [in some] number of [square brackets]'

# Match a string consisting of anything *except* ]
# between literal [ and ]
regex='\[[^]]+\]'
while [[ $str =~ $regex ]]; do
    m=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
    echo "$m"
    str=${str##*"$m"}  # Remove the longest prefix ending with the match
done
```

Technically, you don't need a capture group, just a regular expression that will match *exactly* the string you want to capture, since `=~` will match the first one.

Comment: Nice trick. Just need remove the **shortest** prefix `${str#*"$m"}` because for example for the string `x [a] x [b] x [a] x [a] x [c]` it will print only `a c` instead of the `a b a a c`.

Answer (score 1):

In bash:

For a low number of matches you can use:

```
#!/bin/bash
a='some [values] in string [enclosed] [in some] number of [square brackets]'
reg='[^[]*\[([^]]*)\]'
regex="$reg$reg$reg$reg"
[[ $a =~ $regex ]]
printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}"; echo
```

The reg selects an string that

- has no `[` (`[^[]*`),
- followed by a `[`,
- followed by several **not** `]` (`[^]]*`),
- followed by a `]`.

The parenthesis capture the value inside the brackets.

A repeated use of reg in regex allows the capture of the several strings inside brackets. That could be extended to a (small) number of matches. For a general solution you would need a loop, or to use awk.

On execution, the script above will print:

```
$ ./script
values
enclosed
in some
square brackets
```